# Unable to start jenkins in EC2-AWS linux server

Tags: jenkins

I have installed java 1.8.* and set the `JAVA_HOME` path, and installed Jenkins from the official website as below in AWS EC2 Linux instance.

Java path: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64` and
`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME:$MAVEN_HOME:$M2`

Jenkins commands used for installation:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo \
    https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io.key
sudo yum upgrade
# Add required dependencies for the jenkins package
sudo yum install jenkins
sudo systemctl start jenkins
```

But jenkins failed to start. I don't have tomcat installed so port 8080 should be available. I have also set Java path at `/etc/init.d/jenkins` file
under section candidates="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/bin/java"
started Jenkins as per above command, but the service was failing.
Error Description as  below:

```
 systemctl start jenkins
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl status jenkins.service`

```
jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2022-12-21 10:15:02 UTC; 10s ago
  Process: 20467 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 20467 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
jenkins.service failed.
 jenkins.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
 Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
start request repeated too quickly for jenkins.service
Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
jenkins.service failed.
```

request if anybody has solution for this, please do help with the resolution. Expecting service should start and running and at browser console I should get the Unlock Jenkins screen window.

Thanks

Comment: If you just ["installed jenkins from the official website"](https://www.jenkins.io/download/), the [Java Requirement](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/) is Java 11, [since 2.361.1](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2022/06/28/require-java-11/). btw: Do not upgrade Jenkins via UI if installed via package or image; upgrade the package or image.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian W. after installing JDK11 the problem got resolved.